# How to set up properly Cron job on shared hosting

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I'm trying to set up correctly the Cron job for my Magento so i can send the newsletter.

I've seen many guides but any of them worked for me.

Here is my PHP info file: http://sportsdirect.bg/phpinfo.php

For now any Cron job is running for my Magento, i need to set it up!

Can you please give me the command i should place in my cPanel so it will run ot every 5 minutes.

My Magento version is 1.9.0.1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tony,it total depend o n share hosting feaure

Comment: have you using magento default  newsletter feature

Answer (score 1):

In shared hosting (using cPanel), you can setup your cron in Advanced section -> Cron Jobs

In Common Settings field, select once every five minutes in the dropdown.

In Command, put the following action (if your Magento root is public_html)

```
/bin/sh /home/sportsdi/public_html/cron.sh
```

Add that cron job and your cron should be up and running.

Comment: And if the shared hosting cPanel setup denies running shell scripts from cron for security reasons, then run cron.php instead.