# catalog price rules disappear after mid night

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, catalog-price-rules

[image]we have a problem with catalog price rules in 1.9.0

we have some 1000 products in a site.

we applied catalog price rules to give discount for 500 products.

i did't gave any date limit for catalog price rules

those special prices are displaying only until mid night.

next day, after mid- night special prices are not displaying in site.

cron is working fine.

please help me to find some solution.

Comment: Can you please verify your Cron is setup properly? Following my answer here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64876/how-to-set-up-properly-cron-job-on-shared-hosting/64898#64898

Comment: @Alvin, please check here :  http://prntscr.com/75e1fb i used this extension  :  http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html i am getting message as in the image.

Comment: please check the updated question with image.

Comment: How long does the cron take (if u receive cron-mails - prints in the scheduler scripts are ugly but quick)? Perhaps your AOE-scheduler could help. Are there some other process running (db-backup?) Is the sequence right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to do reindexing. Please reindex once then check it is working or not.

Comment: I reindexed everyhting using "Index management" in admin panel. 

every status is "ready" ,but still it disappeared today also.

Comment: can you give me access of admin panel because it's tough to know the problem without that?

Comment: hi @saurabh  this is my cron settings : http://prntscr.com/75dnv9

if you tell what you need to see, i will post the screen shots, i am not in a position to give credentials....

Answer (score 5):

source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280095/magento-catalog-price-rule-disappears-at-night

credits for genius "Alexei Yerofeyev".  mostly i will never forget this man.

Yes, this is a bug in Magento (or some logic beyond my understanding). When Magento displays products on frontend, it checks if there are catalog rules for this date. And the date used for this check is your local, so in your case GMT+5. However, when catalog rules are being applied, it uses GMT date. So that means that you aren't able to apply rules until 5 AM.

The problem is in Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Action_Index_Refresh::execute() function. You will have to rewrite this function/class either in your extension, or via the local version of the file.

You have to replace line 121 here :

```
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Action/Index/Refresh.php

$timestamp = $coreDate->gmtTimestamp('Today');
```

with this line:

```
$timestamp = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date(null, null, null, true)->get(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);
```

After that you should be able to apply the rules.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for 1.9.2.2. I have still strange catalog rules disappering. Any fixes? I use GMT+2 timezone. Any other hints? I also tried this extension https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fix-catalog-rules.html but it got even worse. Catalog Price resets were triggered each day. now its triggered when some things are changed in store - like extension is updated etc.

Comment: @sellio please post new question with what and all you tried and other details, hopefully you will get an answer.....

Answer (score 2):

As stated above by @Baby-in-Magento the problem is with the indexer.

I had this problem as well, the issue exists when there is an offset of the local timezone greater than +01:00.

Basically just because magento is using the gmtTimestamp for the rule date which in the above stated case results in the day before today.

Therefor I developed a small module https://github.com/Chuvisco88/Chuvisco_CatalogRuleFix to fix the issue.
If someone ever has this problem, please give it a try.

Comment: Chuvisco, than you for this. I installed your solution yesterday and today - voila! The rules still show up after 0100 AM. Thanks a lot! [Magento 1.9.3.2]

Answer (score 1):

In my setup the solution was to set the mysql timezone same as the magento timezone
I managed it by using this initStatement in my local.xml file