# Products discount is expiring before date of expiration date in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, discount, catalog-price-rules, catalog-rules

i have set 10% discount to all products in magento from 26-10-2016 to 12-11-2016 but its expiring before 12-11-2016. but when i am reseting it from admin its again showing.

Comment: is there any difference in server time?

Comment: are you asking about cron job ...

Comment: no, i meant check your server time in which site is hosted.

Comment: server time is right

Comment: on 26-10-2016 i have set discount which will be expire on 12-11-2016  but its expired on 06-11-2016 and when on 07-11-2016 i saved again its working fine

Comment: Please also cross check the Magento Time zone, and try to find out time difference between your time zone and Magento time zone

Comment: @VivekKhandelwal i found solution here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67970/catalog-price-rules-disappear-after-mid-night