# Magento 1.9.1.0 catalog price rules and new product issue

Tags: new-products, catalog-rules

A friend asked me to help him to understand an issue on his magento.
His catalog price rules doesn't apply anymore after two days.
New product doesn't take care of end date.

I found a module on magento connect to fix catalog price rules issue but can't install it because of PHP version (need 5.4 max).

Have you any idea ? I think that these two issues can have the same origin but any idea of why..

Thanks for all

Comment: Magento is running on which PHP version ?  This issues occurs  generally when the server is not configured well as per the Magento version and cron setup as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [catalog price rules disappear after mid night](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67970/catalog-price-rules-disappear-after-mid-night)

Answer (score 0):

`catalog price rules`- most killing part in magento, it may be because of many reasons - `cron jobs` in server not working & wrong  configuration in backend  , difference in  `server` & `magento` time , check this [link once](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67970/catalog-price-rules-disappear-after-mid-night) .

regarding installing extension, please tell how you tried to install [ through magento connect ? ] if so , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla).

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....